# Why did Loki give in?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

I can understand why the two Infinity Stones Thanos got off-screen weren't going to pose a particular problem.  But of the ones we see on-screen, there seem to be a couple that were rather too easy - first, the Tesseract:

> Why did Loki give it up to save Thor?  It's not like they're best buddies, and stopping Thanos from killing half the universe is surely worth a little collateral damage.  Given where Loki had it stashed, if Loki had held firm then Thanos would never have got it.  Also, Loki isn't a hero with principles, which could be an argument for why Gamora gave up the Soul Stone.

Why was it all so relatively effortless?

Comment: This sounds like three separate questions, about three separate characters' decisions. They should probably be posted separated - "Why did Loki do this?", "Why did Gamora do this?", and "Why did Dr. Strange do this?" Though the answer to the third one is almost certainly unanswerable right now, because it will probably be covered in the next film.

Comment: @recognizer Done

Comment: Doctor Strange one is the easiest to answer, @recognizer, he saw 14 million timelines and only one where they won. He made the decision to steer destiny into that direction.

Comment: @Edlothiad Per the original wording of the question, the asker acknowledges that, but still wants further explanation. Once we've established that fact and are still asking "but what's the deal?", the question is definitely a nonstarter unless Avengers 4 clarifies it.

Comment: @recognizer ah I understand, I hadn't read the original version just the comments. That seems fair enough.

Comment: For the record, I never gave in!

Answer (score 6):

Loki initially didn't want to give up the Tesseract. When Thanos first asks him and Thor, Thor even says:

> "We don't have the Tesseract" and that it was destroyed in the explosion of Asgard (or something along those lines.)

Loki doesn't confirm or deny this, and Thanos says:

> That he's going to kill or maim Thor, and Loki mocks him and says, go ahead.

Thanos then proceeds to:

> Torture Thor with the Power Stone. Loki suddenly breaks down, and hands over the Tesseract to Thanos. (Thor is surprised at this, and tells Loki, "You are truly lost, brother".)

However, it doesn't stop there, because

> Loki tries to fool Thanos into convincing him to let Loki join his team, but as he steps closer to the Titan, he tries to kill Thanos with a hidden knife, and Thanos uses the Power Stone to stop him.

The following isn't explained in the movie, but based on the sequence of events, my take is that this is what was going on in Loki's mind:

> Loki gave up the Space Stone to stop Thor from getting tortured further. But he doesn't want Thanos to get the Space Stone either, and tries to fool Thanos into thinking that he wants to join Thanos' team, and brings up a hidden knife to strike at Thanos. But Thanos somehow sees this and stops him with the Power Stone.

Comment: Maybe the "somehow" in your last paragraph has something to do with Loki bragging about being the "God of Mischief" :)